# Saving and Loading FlannBasedMatcher

Tags: c++, opencv

Training an OpenCV DescriptorMatcher can be a time consuming operation if the training image set is large. So it seems that saving the trained DescriptorMatcher data to disk for reloading later would be a pretty obvious thing to want to do.

Unfortunately there does not appear to be any obvious solution to this need.

The closest I've come to finding an answer is [this thread in the OpenCV discussion group](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/68519). The thread started in 2009, and people are still looking for an answer in 2011!

This code snippet taken from that thread looks like it should reload an index from a file:

```
FileStorage fs("data.xml",FileStorage::READ);
Mat data;
fs["mtx"] >> data;
flann::Index idx(data,"index.bin");
```

But I haven't been able to figure out from this how to implement complete save/load functionality.

Just in case it is relevant, I'm using OpenCV 2.3.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did not see an answer to this on forums or mailing list. I had to dig into the OpenCV source code (2.4.5) to see how this needs to be done. It requires subclassing to get at the protected members of FlannBasedMatcher.

The key is setting the algorithm to `FLANN_INDEX_SAVED` and the file name on the `indexParams`.

Also of note:

- The descriptors must be passed to add() before readIndex()
- For the index to be built, you must do a match on it first, then call write(). train() does not seem to do anything except construct the matcher (doesn't feed it descriptors)
- This works with SURF descriptors. For a complete solution it may be necessary to save/restore the IndexParams and/or SearchParams of the matcher as well.

Next thing to do is compress the index (with gzip), it can be 3-4 times smaller and cost to decompress is relatively low. This would have to be a patch in OpenCV.

```
class SaveableMatcher : public cv::FlannBasedMatcher
{
public:
SaveableMatcher()
{
}

virtual ~SaveableMatcher()
{
}

void printParams()
{
    printf("SaveableMatcher::printParams: \n\t"
        "addedDescCount=%d\n\t"
        "flan distance_t=%d\n\t"
        "flan algorithm_t=%d\n",
        addedDescCount,
        flannIndex->getDistance(),
        flannIndex->getAlgorithm());

    vector<std::string> names;
    vector<int> types;
    vector<std::string> strValues;
    vector<double> numValues;

    indexParams->getAll(names, types, strValues, numValues);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
        printf("\tindex param: %s:\t type=%d val=%s %.2f\n",
                names[i].c_str(), types[i],
                strValues[i].c_str(), numValues[i]);

    names.clear();
    types.clear();
    strValues.clear();
    numValues.clear();
    searchParams->getAll(names, types, strValues, numValues);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
        printf("\tsearch param: %s:\t type=%d val=%s %.2f\n",
                names[i].c_str(), types[i],
                strValues[i].c_str(), numValues[i]);
}

void readIndex(const char* filename)
{
    indexParams->setAlgorithm(cvflann::FLANN_INDEX_SAVED);
    indexParams->setString("filename", filename);

    // construct flannIndex now, so printParams works
    train();

    printParams();
}

void writeIndex(const char* filename)
{
    printParams();
    flannIndex->save(filename);
}
};
```

Comment: Note: as I understand it, the descriptors themselves must be serialized/deserialized separately. Upon loading, _prior_ to calling readIndex, the descriptors must be deserialized and added (i.e., with FlannBasedMatcher::add).

Answer (score 3):

In OpenCV 2.4.0 (but also in 2.3.1a) there are:

```
// Reads matcher object from a file node
virtual void read( const FileNode& );
// Writes matcher object to a file storage
virtual void write( FileStorage& ) const;
```

that are implemented at least for the FlannDescriptorMatcher but the implementation seems to save just the IndexParams of the matcher. Instead flann::Index_ has a save and load methods (in 2.3.1 there's save while load seems to be available using a SavedIndexParams

Comment: Yes, the read and write functions only save the IndexParams. I'll take a look at the other functions you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

This question was asked a long time ago, so you probably have your answer already, but I just implemented something using code similar to what you show. I did not save the DescriptorMatcher, but created a descriptors.xml file for each image in the collection, and then loaded all these into a Vector to be used as input to the train() call.
This reduced the run time of the program from 2 minutes to 5 seconds, but it takes 3-4 seconds to load the descriptors into the Vector. 
It would be handy to load the entire trained index. I am still looking for a way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the OpenCV 3.2.0 code and found that the Flann-based matcher's write()/read() function still doesn't save/load the trained data. Inspired by wally's answer, I created a similar savable matcher class inherited from FlannBasedMatcher. Note that this savable matcher currently only works with SURF descriptors.

This savable class FlannBasedSavableMatcher writes indexParams, searchParams, and trained descriptors into an xml/yml file but has to write flannIndex into a separate binary file since the save() method of flannIndex only supports the raw binary format.

Below is the class header.

```
#ifndef INCLUDES_FLANNBASEDSAVABLEMATCHER_H_
#define INCLUDES_FLANNBASEDSAVABLEMATCHER_H_

#include <string>

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d.hpp>

namespace cv
{

class FlannBasedSavableMatcher : public FlannBasedMatcher
{
private:
    std::vector<std::string> trainedImgFilenameList;
    std::string flannIndexFileDir;
    std::string flannIndexFilename;

public:
    FlannBasedSavableMatcher();
    virtual ~FlannBasedSavableMatcher();

    std::vector<std::string> getTrainedImgFilenameList();
    void setTrainedImgFilenameList(const std::vector<std::string>& imgFilenameList);
    void setFlannIndexFileDir(const std::string& dir);
    void setFlannIndexFilename(const std::string& filename);

    virtual void read(const FileNode& fn);
    virtual void write(FileStorage& fs) const;

    static Ptr<FlannBasedSavableMatcher> create();
};

}

#endif /* INCLUDES_FLANNBASEDSAVABLEMATCHER_H_ */
```

The source file can be found at 
https://github.com/renweizhukov/LearningOpenCV/blob/master/FlannKnnSavableMatching1toN/src/FlannBasedSavableMatcher.cpp, while a sample usage can be found at 
https://github.com/renweizhukov/LearningOpenCV/blob/master/FlannKnnSavableMatching1toN/src/main.cpp.